# Issue when compiling

Tags: clojure

I keep getting the following error, its most likely something obvious but i'm rather new to this. Any help would be appreciated. I'm quite sure there error is in this section of the code.

```
(b/defcomponent client {:bounce/deps #{config/value}}
  (log/info "Connecting to Discord")
  (let [token (get-in config/value [:discord :token])
        client (if token
                 (.. (ClientBuilder.)
                     (withToken token)
                     login)
                 (throw (Error. "Discord token not found, please set {:discord {:token \"...\"}} in `config/config.edn`.")))]
```

Had a look through where i believe the error is, cant seem to figure it out though.

```
(ns snowball.discord
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]
            [clojure.core.async :as a]
            [bounce.system :as b]
            [taoensso.timbre :as log]
            [camel-snake-kebab.core :as csk]
            [snowball.config :as config]
            [snowball.util :as util])
  (:import [sx.blah.discord.api ClientBuilder]
           [sx.blah.discord.util.audio AudioPlayer]
           [sx.blah.discord.handle.audio IAudioReceiver]
           [sx.blah.discord.api.events IListener]))

(defn event->keyword [c]
  (-> (str c)
      (str/split #"\.")
      (last)
      (str/replace #"Event.*$" "")
      (csk/->kebab-case-keyword)))

(defmulti handle-event! (fn [c] (event->keyword c)))
(defmethod handle-event! :default [_] nil)

(declare client)

(defn ready? []
  (some-> client .isReady))

(defn poll-until-ready []
  (let [poll-ms (get-in config/value [:discord :poll-ms])]
    (log/info "Connected, waiting until ready")
    (util/poll-while poll-ms (complement ready?) #(log/info "Not ready, sleeping for" (str poll-ms "ms")))
    (log/info "Ready")))

(defn channels []
  (some-> client .getVoiceChannels seq))

(defn channel-users [channel]
  (some-> channel .getConnectedUsers seq))

(defn current-channel []
  (some-> client .getConnectedVoiceChannels seq first))

(defn ->name [entity]
  (some-> entity .getName))

(defn ->id [entity]
  (some-> entity .getLongID))

(defn leave! [channel]
  (when channel
    (log/info "Leaving" (->name channel))
    (.leave channel)))

(defn join! [channel]
  (when channel
    (log/info "Joining" (->name channel))
    (.join channel)))

(defn bot? [user]
  (some-> user .isBot))

(defn muted? [user]
  (when user
    (let [voice-state (first (.. user getVoiceStates values))]
      (or (.isMuted voice-state)
          (.isSelfMuted voice-state)
          (.isSuppressed voice-state)))))

(defn can-speak? [user]
  (not (or (bot? user) (muted? user))))

(defn has-speaking-users? [channel]
  (->> (channel-users channel)
       (filter can-speak?)
       (seq)
       (boolean)))

(defn default-guild []
  (some-> client .getGuilds seq first))

(defn guild-users []
  (some-> (default-guild) .getUsers))

(defn guild-text-channels []
  (some-> (default-guild) .getChannels))

(defn guild-voice-channels []
  (some-> (default-guild) .getVoiceChannels))

(defn move-user-to-voice-channel [user channel]
  (when (and user channel)
    (try
      (.moveToVoiceChannel user channel)
      (catch Exception e
        (log/warn "Tried to move a user to a voice channel that isn't connected to voice already")))))

(defn play! [audio]
  (when audio
    (when-let [guild (default-guild)]
      (doto (AudioPlayer/getAudioPlayerForGuild guild)
        (.clear)
        (.queue audio)))))

(defn send! [channel-id message]
  (when-let [channel (.getChannelByID (default-guild) channel-id)]
    (log/info "Sending message to" channel-id "-" message)
    (.sendMessage channel message)))

(defmethod handle-event! :reconnect-success [_]
  (log/info "Reconnection detected, leaving any existing voice channels to avoid weird state")
  (poll-until-ready)
  (when-let [channel (current-channel)]
    (leave! channel)))

(defn audio-manager []
  (some-> (default-guild) .getAudioManager))

(defrecord AudioEvent [audio user])

(defn subscribe-audio! [f]
  (let [sub! (atom nil)
        closed?! (atom false)
        sub-chan (a/go-loop []
                   (when-not @closed?!
                     (a/<! (a/timeout (get-in config/value [:discord :poll-ms])))
                     (if-let [am (audio-manager)]
                       (try
                         (let [sub (reify IAudioReceiver
                                     (receive [_ audio user _ _]
                                       (try
                                         (when-not (bot? user)
                                           (f (AudioEvent. audio user)))
                                         (catch Exception e
                                           (log/error "Caught error while passing audio event to subscription handler" e)))))]
                           (reset! sub! sub)
                           (log/info "Audio manager exists, subscribing to audio")
                           (.subscribeReceiver am sub))
                         (catch Exception e
                           (log/error "Caught error while setting up audio subscription" e)))
                       (recur))))]

    (fn []
      (when-let [sub @sub!]
        (reset! closed?! true)
        (a/close! sub-chan)
        (.unsubscribeReceiver (audio-manager) sub)))))

(b/defcomponent client {:bounce/deps #{config/value}}
  (log/info "Connecting to Discord")
  (let [token (get-in config/value [:discord :token])
        client (if token
                 (.. (ClientBuilder.)
                     (withToken token)
                     login)
                 (throw (Error. "Discord token not found, please set {:discord {:token \"...\"}} in `config/config.edn`.")))]

    (.registerListener
      (.getDispatcher client)
      (reify IListener
        (handle [_ event]
          (handle-event! event))))

    (with-redefs [client client]
      (poll-until-ready))

    (b/with-stop client
      (log/info "Shutting down Discord connection")
      (.logout client))))

(b/defcomponent audio-chan {:bounce/deps #{client}}
  (log/info "Starting audio channel from subscription")
  (let [audio-chan (a/chan (a/sliding-buffer 100))
        sub (subscribe-audio!
              (fn [event]
                (a/go
                  (a/put! audio-chan event))))]
    (b/with-stop audio-chan
      (log/info "Closing audio channel and unsubscribing")
      (sub)
      (a/close! audio-chan))))
```

Below is the error i am getting

```
>     make
>     ./run.sh
>     19-05-25 19:05:45 localhost INFO [snowball.main:6] - Starting components...
>     19-05-25 19:05:47 localhost INFO [snowball.config:16] - Loading base config from config.base.edn and user config from
> config/config.edn
>     19-05-25 19:05:47 localhost INFO [snowball.discord:150] - Connecting to Discord
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (clojure.lang.Symbol is in unnamed module of loader 'app';
> java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
>             at snowball.discord$eval12963$start_client__12964.invoke(discord.clj:152)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
>             at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
>             at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
>             at bounce.system$start_system$fn__479$fn__480.invoke(system.clj:68)
>             at bounce.system$start_system$fn__479$fn__480$fn__481.invoke(system.clj:71)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
>             at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
>             at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.invokeStatic(core.clj:1973)
>             at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1973)
>             at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
>             at bounce.system$start_system$fn__479$fn__480.invoke(system.clj:69)
>             at bounce.system$start_system.invokeStatic(system.clj:80)
>             at bounce.system$start_system.invoke(system.clj:59)
>             at bounce.system$start_BANG_.invokeStatic(system.clj:122)
>             at bounce.system$start_BANG_.invoke(system.clj:112)
>             at snowball.main$_main.invokeStatic(main.clj:13)
>             at snowball.main$_main.invoke(main.clj:5)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
>             at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
>             at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
>             at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
>             at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:491)
>             at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:487)
>             at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
>             at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
>             at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
>             at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
>             at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
>     Makefile:12: recipe for target 'run' failed
>     make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Comment: What does gcc have to do with this?

Comment: sorry, it was a tag i had in from a previous questions i was going to ask but ended up figuring it out. I asked this question from the tab i already had opened without thinking. My bad.

Comment: Is `snowball` the name of your project or has this to do with the library?  And is this really specific to ubuntu like you state in the question itself?  The error you get there looks like you are passing 'app instead of "app".

Comment: Snowball is the name of the project, just noticed there is a tag for it in there, i approved an edit so i think that's where its came from, ill remove it now. I put ubuntu in the question to specify which OS i was using, should i remove it?

Thanks you the help aswell i'm going to go have a look through.

Comment: It's good to add information about your environment, but it should focus on the "why".  I'd assume, that your code fails anywhere, and while you are only testing it on ubuntu it might lead folks trying to answer astray. So yes, unless you _know_ the problem is specific to ubuntu, i'd remove that and rather make part of the error the subject.

Comment: Could anyone elaborate on the passing 'app instead of "app"? would it be helpful if i upload the project to git?

Answer (score 0):

From this bit:

```
>     19-05-25 19:05:47 localhost INFO [snowball.discord:150] - Connecting to Discord
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
```

It looks like the expression `(get-in config/value [:discord :token])` in line 152 is returning a symbol (a `clojure.lang.Symbol`) instead of a String, and that is causing a `ClassCastException` to be thrown when building the Client class.

I guess what's going on is that you are reading the configuration from an external file or some other source and your token is not properly quoted, so it's being resolved as a Symbol ("a variable name") instead of a String.